# Anti-Alising Circle shape Google Maps V2 Android

Tags: java, android, google-maps

Im having problem drawing a Circle using Google Maps v2 . The Circle displays correctly but the circle's edges are not smooth, they are quite sharp, is there any way to apply Antialising to the shape? Thanks

My code:

```
CircleOptions circleOptions = new CircleOptions()
      .center(point)  
      .radius(500)  
      .fillColor(0x7F0000FF) 
      .strokeColor(Color.rgb(71, 143, 150))
      .strokeWidth(2);
```

Comment: have you tried .strokeWeight(1.5)

Answer (score 0):

I know this is an old question, and I'm not completely answering it, but here's my contribute anyhow:

So far I believe there is no way of doing this in Android. The only workaround is to use a Google Maps Marker and replace its icon with a bitmap of a smooth circle. You will not be able to change it's size, but I think that is pretty much the only limitation of not using a Circle object.

To make things easier, you can even use Android Studio to create a new Image asset, choose Clip Art, and search for "brightness". The first icon will be a perfect circle, which you can then change size and color to your taste. Afterwards, just create a new Bitmap from your newly created drawable:

```
Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.DRAWABLE_NAME_HERE);
```

And create a BitmapDescriptor which is used to give a Google Maps Marker its icon:

```
BitmapDescriptor descriptor = BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromBitmap(bitmap);
```

Having this object defined, you just need to set it as your Marker's icon:

```
Marker.setIcon(descriptor);
```

or

```
MarkerOptions.icon(descriptor);
```

And use these MarkerOptions to create a new Marker.

As I said, this is not the complete answer for your question, but it is the closest thing I know exists. Hope it helps somehow.